# Contradiction in the fact that magnetic fields do zero work

Tags: forces, magnetic-fields, work

Consider a metallic rod hung by two springs (symmetrically), a magnetic field exists out of the plane of our system. At t = 0, we switch on a battery which produces current in wire (left to right in the rod) so now, a force of magnetic origin acts on the rod to pull it down and extend the springs thus magnetic force appears to do work in this case.

So is the fact that magnetic forces don't do work incorrect?
Because I don't think that some other force can do work on the system

Assume the rod and springs to be massless.

Comment: What about the battery pumping charges through the circuit?

Comment: All of that work would translate to heat loss only I've tried it, the numbers match up exactly

Comment: The electrons feel the force of the magnetic field while being accelerated between collisions by the battery's E field providing an average momentum perpendicular to the wire and magnetic field. These collisions with an average side ways momentum causes the springs to stretch so is not all lost in heat.

Comment: In the case you explained, still work done by magnetic field won't be zero and that was my question

Comment: The magnetic force just changes the direction of the charges but does not do work. The side ways momentum all comes from the original acceleration by the E field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Positive work by a magnetic field](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/195032/)